# Django Rest Framework and Sphinx

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-sphinx

I couldn't find `object.inv` for Django Rest Framework.

In Sphinx `conf.py`, I have:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3.5', None),
    'django': ('http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.x/', None),
    'rest_framework': (????, None)
}
```

I've tried with `http://www.django-rest-framework.org/` but:

> WARNING: intersphinx inventory 'http://www.django-rest-framework.org/objects.inv' not fetchable due to : 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/objects.inv

How can I map classes and methods in my docs to DRF?

Comment: The Django Rest Framework documentation (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is not built with Sphinx; it is built with MkDocs. So there is no objects.inv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible.

The Django Rest Framework documentation is not built with Sphinx. It is built with MkDocs.

So there is no `objects.inv` file.